# Which parts of DirectShow's Filter Graph Manager are thread safe?

Tags: thread-safety, directshow

The MSDN doesn't say. [`IGraphBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390085(v=VS.85).aspx) has a function [`Abort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390086(v=VS.85).aspx). That implies that at the very least it's safe to call `Abort` and any one other `IGraphBuilder` function at the same time. With this question, I want to obtain proof that [Filter Graph Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375786(v=VS.85).aspx) is thread safer than that.

Comment: Your proof is in first paragraph of that URL you provided: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375786(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: You mean the "The Filter Graph Manager also handles synchronization" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectShow is thread safe and is typically working on multiple threads even in simple scenarios. For example, a source filter typically owns its own worker thread and streams from there.